# powershell and batch file combination?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a powershell command running when I execute a bat file,
The command is

```
@powershell -command " [long]((date) . touniversaltime() - [datetime]' 1970-01-01 '). totalmilliseconds"
```

I have also used

```
powershell.exe " [long]((date). touniversaltime () -[datetime]'1970-01-01 ') . totalmilliseconds "
```

This returns the correct data to the screen but my question is how do I save this value and use it to attach it to a filename.

Thanking You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f %%x in ('powershell "[long]((date).touniversaltime()-[datetime]'1970-01-01').totalmilliseconds"') do set ms=%%x
rem do whatever you want with %ms%
```

I vaguely remembered the code from an earlier answer of mine. My advice from earlier still stands: Just write your script in PowerShell instead of creating a weird hybrid that's just twice as hard to maintain.